# Make text draggable on Mac?

Tags: macos, drag-and-drop, nstableview

I have an `NSTableView` which holds a bunch of cells. Is it possible (within limits of sandbox) to be able to drag one of these cells to say a text field in Safari and have it insert text from that cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely possible. Check out the [Drag and Drop Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DragandDrop/DragandDrop.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000069-SW1) and the [Pasteboard Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSPasteboard_Class/index.html).